# ByteBuddy call constructor of generated class

Tags: byte-buddy

I am trying to generate a method like this in a generated class

```
static void setDefault(Supplier<?> arg0, String[] arg1, String[] arg2) {
    defaultInstance = new GeneratedClass(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}
```

I am struggling with the API, where I'm currently is

```
        .defineMethod("setDefault", Void.TYPE, Visibility.PACKAGE_PRIVATE, Ownership.STATIC, MethodArguments.PLAIN)
            .withParameters(Supplier.class, String[].class, String[].class)
        .intercept(....)
```

I believe I need `FieldAccessor.ofField` and `MethodCall.construct` however I'm struggling to come up with a `MethodDescription` for the constructor of the to be generated class.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot describe the generated class, you can create an instance of `InstrumentedType.Default` and provide it as a type description.

You should use `MethodCall` which allows you to access parameters from its DSL.